# Problem with switching to next language using the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have two languages installed. English and my mother tongue  (let's say Italian, as an example).

I've configured to change language with `Alt + Shift` from `Switching to another layout` of `Additional Layout Options`.

Assume I have it on Italian. To change language (to English) an `Alt + Shift` is enough. Say now that my keyboard is in English, and I want to change it to Italian. Pressing `Alt + Shift` isn't enough once, but twice.

Why is that? I didn't know how to search this exactly, that's why the title is weirdly formulated either.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: how many layouts do you have? 2 or 3? That is what I would expect if you had 3 layouts total. alt+shift once to get to the second, and then twice to get to the third and then first again.

Comment: @Esther, my input sources (from "Keyboard" settings) are two. English and my other language.

Comment: You seem to have hit [bug #1956916](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916). Please feel free to state that the bug affects you.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I edited the OP. Solution was to disable Wayland.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the answer inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

## OP added the following answer within the question

I am putting it here as OP seems inactive:

> I solved the issue by un-commenting the line (removing the `#`)
> `#WaylandEnable=false` from `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, and then
> rebooting.